# Mask and/or format with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mask

I'm using the standard digitalBush jquery mask plugin. It seems as though I'm fighting with it.

I simply want an input to have a mask (so it'll allow 1 or 2 digits) and then show the word "months" after.

Ie. user can type 3 months or 13 months. I can't seem to do that. Here's as close as I could come, but if the user types just a single digit, it won't append "months" to it. I am using this in conjunction with an HTML5 placeholder plugin.

```
$("#months").mask("9?9 months",{placeholder:" "});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find what your looking for here : [Jquery mask plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputmask)
Example:

```
'm': { //month

"validator": "0[1-9]|1[012]",

"cardinality": 2,

"prevalidator": [{ "validator": "[01]", "cardinality": 1}]

}


$("#month").inputmask("m",{"placeholder" : " "});
```

Comment: this is great, but this mask is fairly buggy. not withstanding that:    $("#month").inputmask("m months",{"placeholder" : " "}); doesn't work because it will display "onths" because m is a special validator...the greedy option doesn't work, which is why i say it's buggy, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: is there a way to escape the m in months? i tried a bunch of options but none worked.

Comment: Just seen your comment, do you have a link to a page so I can see what's going on?

Comment: I put in both the months issue and the bug with just the regular mask. If you put in 1234 for that mask, it should delete that, but it doesn't, which defeats the point of the mask.

Comment: You can also add this `$("#months").inputmask("m",{"placeholder" : "M"});`, as in : "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: Yes I know that works, but I want it to display the word "months" after the number...any thoughts?

Comment: I went back and forth with the developer (super nice guy). He fixed this up and it works fine now. Thanks for pointing me towards this.